# Spinner is not spinning some time

Tags: angularjs, icons

I need to show spinner icon in one place. Here im using angularjs project.

I have class ion-spinner-ios

This is my customized class for spinning

```
.icon.ion-spinner-ios {
    display: inline-block;
    background-size: 20px;
    background-image: url("images/ion-spinner-loader.gif");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
}
```

but some time ie11 doesn't support spinning.

Spinner is not spinning some time not all the times.

What is the feedback in this?

Comment: Its showing on other browsers like Mozila or crome every time  ?

Comment: Most probably it is showing. I didn't get any failure case in other browsers

Answer (score 0):

It is a memory issue most probably. Since sniper is a gif icon here so It should spin regardless of browser and your code. May be when some task is happening, IE is to much busy and image rendering is not happening in that particular time. I think you can not solve this problem. It is a operating system or IE memory issue most probably.

Only you could look your program and if possible change your program for better efficiency and remove all those kind of things which is taking time and making slow your IE.

If possible comment the task what is running behind when spiner is being displayed and test multiple times that spinner is not spinning or not every time. May be you can get some clue.

Comment: Can you suggest on this? Is this better way to use css animation instead of gif? Will it solve this issue?

Comment: If you are using any code which is taking too long to respond same thing may happen for your CSS animation also. So either you need to improve your code efficiency or try other things to check you luck.

Comment: In this case, i am not making any server calls. I am showing loader on some element based on server call response. So. It is not possible to struck the browser from memory